# How do i get double clicks in a canvas

Tags: jquery, html, html5-canvas

I am able to track mouse move. I plan to use same calculations to see what object the mouse is over but canvas appears not to get the double click event (using jquery).

What is the best way to track double clicks? If you suggest keeping track of time than how do i get single clicks and how do i get time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A sample canvas:

```
<canvas id="mycanvas" height="200" width="300"></canvas>
```

Detect double click on canvas:

```
$('#mycanvas').on('dblclick', function() {
  alert('Double clicked');
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/5kzvx/)**